# PWA vs intercepting requests in Web view

Tags: android, angular, progressive-web-apps

I am using a webview to render and for optimisation i am thinking about caching the required css, js and other asset files

Now there are two possibilities for caching.

- Using the javascript interceptor in webview and managing the cache myself.
- Making the website a PWA and letting the app itself manage the cache.

Which approach is recommended ?

Answer (score 1):

With PWAs you can take advantage of different, well tested technologies to improve a web app performance:

- Possibility to use different caching strategies: cache first (typically for supporting offline static content), stale while revalidate, network race, etc.
- Possibility to cache HTTP GET calls, hence not only static data.
- The service worker runs on a thread different from the one used by you web app, therefore it can operate also when the web app is *closed* and it will not affect its performance in case of crash

These are only some of the PWA benefits and you can achieve them with relative low efforts. Therefore from my perspective, I would add *progressive* functionalities to your app.

If you want to deepen the PWA topic, [have a look at a series of articles about PWA I wrote](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da). I start from the theory and I then go deeper and deeper with code samples.